# $\tilde{T} : X/X_0 \to Y $ is also compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

In a normed linear space N, let $B=\{x \in N : |x| <1\}$ . Then define a linear map  $T :N \to N_1$ ,( $N_1$ some normed linear space ) to be compact if  closure of $T(\bar{B})$ is compact in $N_1$ . With this definition I was trying to prove :

> X,Y Banach space. $T : X \to Y$ compact, $X_0$ closed subspace of $X$ s.t. $X_0 \subset Ker(T)$, Then $\tilde{T} : X/X_0 \to Y $ is also compact.

I couldn't figure out how to proceed. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B'=\{x\in X/X_0: |x|<1\}$, $\bar T(B')=T(B)$ since by definition of the norm of a quotient space if $p:X\rightarrow X/X_0$ is the quotient map, $p(B)=B'$. Since $T=\bar T\circ p$ we deduce that $T(B)=\bar T(B')$.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968606/defining-a-norm-in-the-quotient-space-e-m

Comment: So you are saying that $\tilde{T} (B^{\})=T(B)$ readily follows from definitions?

Comment: yes, it comes from definition. Firstly show that $p(B)=B'$ with the definition of the norm of $X/X_0$ provided in the link.